# fixed position of an element inside a container element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a parent div in which I want to make the child div stay fixed if the page is scrolled down.

I've tried to use `position:relative;` for the parent element and `position:fixed;` for the child but it doesn't work because the child div is positioned according to the window object not the parent div.

Is there any workaround for achieving this with CSS? If not, some javascript/Jquery tricks to create this ?

Any hints/suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: well its not clear what exactly u want.. i mean if scroll page parent should be scrolled with page or that also u want to fix?? if that scroll with page then what is the sense to make child fixed??

Comment: what I want is to make the child element act like a an element which has position:fixed, to be visible also when the user scrolls down

Comment: @AlbusShin Thank you, this is what I'm looking for. So there is no method usign just CSS to achieve this ? You should post that as an answer, I will award you.

Comment: Just converted. ;) If it's a specific requirement, it's much easier to use a plugin instead of implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jquery.pin](http://webpop.github.io/jquery.pin) might help you here, I guess

It's a JQuery plugin, the feature is to provide a "*sticky element to quietly hang around as you scroll down*"

Answer (score 6):

Use `position:relative;` for the parent and `position:absolute;` for the child.

For example:

CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that I can do this, what I want is to make the child element act like a an element which has `position:fixed`, to be visible also when the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` is always relative to the window viewport

You can set the child as position absolute and set its top and left position to fixed values.